# Intel Edison app not updating

Tags: javascript, intel-xdk, iot, intel-edison

I installed the IoT XDK and loaded the blink example. The LED on pin 13 blinks! Great! I changed the interval from 1000ms to 100ms and to 3000ms and reuploaded to the Edison. No change. Light still blinks every second same as before. I even changed the app version info to try to force it to see the update.

I must be missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest software update appears to have solved my issue. I can now vary the duration of the LED pause in the sample code and successfully update my app on the Edison.

Answer (score 0):

I've had several, similar, happenings!  What I've done since is get into the routine of:
 + Stopping the app (the far right icon, the one you click to run the app)
 + Then click the stop app icon (next to it on the left)
 + Save my file
 + Click upload
 + Click run

Going through this process I never run into the issue you describe. When I do forget a step, I can often replicate what you experience!
Good luck!

Comment: I was doing all of that. In the end, nothing worked until I updated the firmware and all of the software. Now it works.